Unknown argument 'username'. Available options are marked with?
I get this error: Unknown argument 'username'. Available options are marked with ?.
I am trying to create a new DB entry for the user but keep getting the same error,
i am working with prisma, PostgreSQL and next.js.
what am I doing  wrong?
This is my schema.prisma file:
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  email            String     @unique
  firstName        String?
  lastName         String?
  createdAt        DateTime   @default(now())
  updatedAt        DateTime   @updatedAt
  clerkUserId      String     @unique
  id               Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  username         String     @unique
  createdQuestions Question[]
  joinedQuestions  Question[] @relation("Participants")

model Question {
  ...
}

This is my create user function
const newUser = await prisma.user.create({
        data: {
            clerkUserId: "test_id",
            email: "email@test.com",
            firstName: "test",
            lastName: "test,
            username: "testuser",
        },
    });

This is the error that i get
⨯ PrismaClientValidationError: 
Invalid `prisma.user.create()` invocation:

{
  data: {
    clerkUserId: "test_id",
    email: "email@test.com",
    firstName: "test",
    lastName: "test",
    username: "testuser",
    ~~~~~~~~
?   createdQuestions?: QuestionCreateNestedManyWithoutCreatorInput,
?   joinedQuestions?: QuestionCreateNestedManyWithoutParticipantsInput
  }
}

Unknown argument `username`. Available options are marked with ?.
    at async GET (./app/api/test/route.ts:11:21)
 ⨯ TypeError: The "payload" argument must be of type object. Received null
    at frame (node_modules\next\src\server\patch-error-inspect.ts:89:42)
    ...
    at async Server.requestListener (node_modules\next\src\server\lib\start-server.ts:146:6) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE',
  page: '/api/test'
}

I tried to run prisma generate prisma db pull prisma migrate dev

To apply the generated migration files use prisma migrate deploy, or to push schema changes to db directly (for dev) prisma db push
